# Google logo is out of date

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

With the [changing of Google's logo](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2015/09/google-update.html) fresh in my mind, I happened to be perusing https://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer, and this caught my eye:

[image]

Compare to the new logo:

[image]

Regardless of my thoughts on the change, it's still out of date. And it bugged me. Fix it please.

Comment: I feel kinda dirty tagging this as a [bug], it's so minor, but none of the other tags really work.

Comment: **Pre-emptive note:** We are not going to get into wars and debates about whether people *like* Google's new logo here - this is not the place. Please take that to Reddit or elsewhere.

Comment: @animuson I can see your point, but surely people's opinion in whether we should or should not replace the logo is valid community feedback, opinion, and voting. If Stack want to overrule and decide themselves fine, but this is a community driven site and MSE is where we discuss such things "It's built and run by *you* as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites" so far, no-one is "war-ing" anymore than any other discussion or feature request where community thrash out what it wants for the site(s).

Comment: @James Whether we use Google's official logo is not a community decision. It's really Google's decision, and if they decide that people shouldn't use their old logo anymore, eventually we have to comply whether we or our community wants us to do so. Considering they're a paying customer, it's *even moreso* their decision which logo gets used.

Comment: The logo just came out today (in my timezone)... even Google hasn't updated the logo on their Android apps. Edit: okay, they are now starting to update them.

Comment: BTW, can anyone point me to the correct resource for Google logo terms of use. I found [using the logo](http://www.google.com/permissions/using-the-logo.html) page but doesn't say anything about getting rid of old logo usage or must comply with new logo...

Comment: @HackerKarma According to [this page](http://www.google.com/permissions/trademark/rules.html), one is to "[u]se only Google-approved artwork when using Google's logos." Presumably, an old logo could become unapproved.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thanks. I guess we just have to assume that's what that means. Such a huge company but does not have proper page with examples of do's and don'ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated the logo to use Google's serif-less latest and greatest. Please let us know if you see any instances missed.