# Google logo is out of date (follow-up)

Tags: bug, design, login, mobile-web, google

Related: [Google logo is out of date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264630/168244)

The Google+ logo associated with logging in is still out-of-date.

Here's a view of the desktop login screen:

[image]

Here's a view of the mobile theme login screen:

[image]

Here's a view of the iPhone app login screen:

[image]

The new [Google+ login options](https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines?hl=en) look like this:

[image]

or like [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines):

[image]

with some custom options available.

Comment: Well, Google itself is still not really using it, e.g. in [this official page](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button): http://i.stack.imgur.com/WPVIg.png so they can't expect others to use it. As far as I can tell, it's just some additional option, not replacing the old logo like in the case of the previous report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is now up to date according to your post:

[image]